# How to know the Shopify username who triggered a webhook?

Tags: shopify, webhooks

I have a `product/update` Shopify webhook. When the webhook event comes, I see the JSON payload but I don't get any clue about who updated the product. I need the username or email or whatever to identify the user who triggered the webhook. Is that even possible ? If yes, how ?

Answer (score 1):

As per [Shopify Documentation](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/events/webhook), **product/update** hook does not contain any information regarding the user who triggered the action. However, if it is extremely important for you to find out the user, a workaround is to use the [Shopify Events API](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/events/event#properties). As you already have the Product ID in the recieved webhook, you may issue another call to

> GET /admin/products/#{product_id}/events.json

and in the response

```
{
  "events": [
    {
      "id": 677313116,
      "subject_id": 921728736,
      "created_at": "2008-01-10T08:00:00-05:00",
      "subject_type": "Product",
      "verb": "create",
      "arguments": [
        "IPod Touch 8GB"
      ],
      "body": null,
      "message": "Product was created: <a href="https://apple.myshopify.com/admin/products/921728736">IPod Touch 8GB</a>.",
      "author": "Shopify",
      "description": "Product was created: IPod Touch 8GB.",
      "path": "/admin/products/921728736"
    }
  ]
}
```

you will have the **author** field. You may further filter the result using **verb** and **created_at** fields.

The [supported events](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/events/event#products) are

[image]

But I am also only able to get the created, published and unpublished events.

Comment: What is the value of the **author** field? What does "Shopify" mean? Can you explain how you use that field?

Comment: @Bilal That api end point doesn't return product update events. It only shows product create events.

Comment: @David Lazar the author field represent the Shopify name of user who performed the action.

Comment: @Haris Das I have verified it before posting the answer.  I cannot share the response because of personal data in response but it returns all the events like product created, edited etc along with the author that is the name of the user who performed the action.

Comment: @BilalAkbar I tried 3 more times, but no luck. It only returns product create events. Should I enable something in my account ?

Comment: @HariDas I have added more info to the answer.

Comment: @BilalAkbar I see, but update is very very important for me